# how to do port forwarding with C++ like 'adb forward tcp:8081 tcp:8082'

Tags: android, c++, sockets, tcp

I want to establish a connection between PC and phone. PC serves as client, and PC end codes are written with C++ or C. On the other hand, phone serves as server, and phone end codes are written with Android. This two devices are connected with USB cable which they use to communicate with each other, that means the server(the phone) does not have an fixed IP. For the sake of the two devices can communicate, we must do port forwarding on the client side(i guess) . I've realize the client with Java(codes like below), but i do know little about C++/C , i don't know how to realize the port forwarding with C++/C, either i don't know realization of the client with C++/C, hoping someone can help me.

```
try {
    // how to realize sentence below with C++
    Runtime.getRuntime().exec("adb forward tcp:8081 tcp:8082");
    Thread.sleep(TIME_SLEEP);
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

Socket socket = null;
try {
    InetAddress serveraddr = null;
    serveraddr = InetAddress.getByName("127.0.0.1");
    socket = new Socket(serveraddr, 8081);      
} catch (UnknownHostException e1) {
    e1.printStackTrace();
} catch (Exception e2) {
    e2.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've solve this problem. Solution contains two .h files and one cpp file. Codes list as below:

InitSock.h

```
#include <winsock2.h>
#include <stdlib.h> 
#include <conio.h> 
#include <stdio.h> 
#pragma comment(lib, "WS2_32")  // link to WS2_32.lib
class CInitSock     
{
public:
    CInitSock(BYTE minorVer = 2, BYTE majorVer = 2)
    {
        // init WS2_32.dll
        WSADATA wsaData;
        WORD sockVersion = MAKEWORD(minorVer, majorVer);
        if(::WSAStartup(sockVersion, &wsaData) != 0)
        {
            exit(0);
        }
    }
    ~CInitSock()
    {   
        ::WSACleanup(); 
    }
};
```

SocketDll.h

```
#pragma once 
#define DLL_EXPORT __declspec(dllexport)  
extern "C" DLL_EXPORT void startSocket();
```

SocketDll.cpp

```
#include "InitSock.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>  
#include <process.h>
using namespace std;

CInitSock initSock;     // init lib Winsock

#include "SocketDll.h" 

void startSocket() 
{ 
    // port forwarding(mapping)
    system("adb forward tcp:8081 tcp:8082");

    // new socket
    SOCKET s = ::socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);
    if(s == INVALID_SOCKET)
    {
        printf(" Failed socket() /n");
        return;
    }

    sockaddr_in servAddr; 
    servAddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    servAddr.sin_port = htons(8081);

    // set up ip
    servAddr.sin_addr.S_un.S_addr = inet_addr("127.0.0.1");

    if(::connect(s, (sockaddr*)&servAddr, sizeof(servAddr)) == -1)
    {
        printf(" Failed connect() /n");
        return;
    } else {
        cout << "connect successed!" << endl;
    }

    char buff[256];
    char szText[256] ;

    while(TRUE)
    {
        // send datas to server
        cin>>szText ;
        szText[255] = '/0';
        ::send(s, szText, strlen(szText), 0) ;

        // receiver datas from server
        int nRecv = ::recv(s, buff, 256, 0);
        if(nRecv > 0)
        {
            buff[nRecv] = '/0';
            printf("data received：%s/n", buff);
        }

    }

    // close socket
    ::closesocket(s); 
}
```